# ScriptResourceDefinition Path not Used

Tags: c#, asp.net, webpack, webforms, bundling-and-minification

I have been following Cecil Phillip's [Setting up Webpack in ASP.NET Web Forms](https://cecilphillip.com/setting-up-webpack-in-asp-net-web-forms/) to get familiar with the Webpack utility.  I have gotten most of the way through it, but am having trouble with a section near the end ([Registering with the ScriptManager](https://cecilphillip.com/setting-up-webpack-in-asp-net-web-forms/#registeringwiththescriptmanager)).

I have added a `ScriptResourceDefinition` with the `Path` and `DebugPath` set to the minified and unminified versions of the Webpack output, respectively.  When I load the page in Debug build, I get the expected `DebugPath` script.  However, when I load it in Release build, rather than the expected `Path` script, I again get the `DebugPath`.  Any idea why this is, and how I can get the correct `Path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out.  Turns out I had made some false assumptions on how the `ScriptManager` worked.  Here's my train of thought --

- Researched [ScriptResourceDefinition.DebugPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptresourcedefinition.debugpath?view=netframework-4.7.2):

  > Gets or sets the debug mode path of the script resource that is used when debug mode is enabled.
- Looked  up the "See Also" link to [Debugging and Tracing ASP.NET AJAX Applications Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb398817(v=vs.140)#setting-the-application-from-debug-to-release-mode-for-deployment) referenced at the bottom:

  > When you deploy a release version of an WebForms application that uses Microsoft Ajax, 
  >   set the application to release mode. This makes sure that ASP.NET uses
  >   the performance-optimized release version of the Microsoft Ajax
  >   libraries. If you have created debug and release versions of your
  >   custom script files and script resources, ASP.NET also uses the
  >   release versions. To set the application to release mode, do the
  >   following:
  >
  > - In the Web.config file, if the compilation element contains a debug
  >     attribute, make sure that the debug attribute is set to false.
  > - Make sure that any Web page that contains a ScriptManager control has
  >     its ScriptMode property set to Release.
- Looked further into [ScriptManager.ScriptMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.scriptmode?view=netframework-4.7.2):

  > The ScriptMode property specifies whether the ScriptManager control should render debug or release versions of client script libraries. This value can be superseded by values that are set in the configuration file and in the page directive.
  > ...
  >   [By default] Debug versions of client script libraries are used in the Web page when the retail attribute of the deployment configuration element is set to false. Otherwise, the release versions of client script libraries are used.

To test this, I tried setting `ScriptMode` to `Release` and it loaded the correct file.